# RegEx for ignoring parentheses in a string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

These is a string like this:

```
strs = "Tierd-Branden This is (L.A.) 105  / New (Even L.A.A)"
```

After trying the following code, I don't get my expected output.

and this is my code:

```
import re, itertools
strs = "Tierd-Branden This is (U.C.) 105  / New (Even L.A.A)"
print re.findall(r"[\w']+[\w\.]", strs)
```

I expect This:

```
['Tierd', 'Branden', 'This', 'is', 'L.A.', '105', 'New', 'Even', 'L.A.A']
```

But, I get this:

```
['Tierd', 'Branden', 'This', 'is', 'L.', 'A.', '105', 'New', 'Even', 'L.', 'A.']
```

My question is how to keep content of parenthesis with <kbd>**.**</kbd> linked as a list element?

Comment: Use `r"[\w'.]+"` or `r"\w[\w'.]*"` (if the word char must come first). See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMfpEm/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[\w']+[\w\.]` pattern matches 1 or more word or `'` chars and then a word or `.` char. Hence, it cannot match chunks of word or `'` chars that have more than 1 dot in them.

I suggest using

```
r"\w[\w'.]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMfpEm/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cw%5B%5Cw'.%5D*):

[image]

**Details**

- `\w` - a word char
- `[\w'.]*` - 0 or more word, `'` and `.` chars.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/leTDsO/1/) might return your desired output, which simply you can list all your desired chars in the <kbd>[]</kbd>. You might use a capturing group, if you wish, just to simply call it using <kbd>$1</kbd>. You can add any other chars that you may wish/have in the <kbd>[]</kbd>, and if those chars might be metachars, you can use <kbd>\</kbd> for escaping.

```
([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)
```

[image]

You can remove the capturing group, and it might still work:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\.]+
```

Comment: I would suggest to avoid using <kbd> tags, instead use back quotes (`) for better readability.